# Any difference between `var x` and `int x`?

Tags: java

Is there a difference between declaring `var x` and `int x`?

```
//Java 8
int x = 10;

//Java 10
var x = 10;
```

Comment: Java 8 example requires you to explicitly declare the type of the variable. Java 10 example allows you to use type inference; the compiler will figure out the variable's type for you

Comment: the only difference is that first one *forces* the correct type on right side (e.g. `var x = 10.0;`or `var x = "10";` will compile, probably breaking some lines later)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no run-time difference. `var` is compile-time syntactical sugar. If you replace `var` with the inferred type (`int`) you get identical results.

Comment: As a reference to back John up: https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-10-var-type-inference/#No-This-Is-Not-JavaScript